# HTML5 Canvas A* Star Path finding

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, path-finding

I am trying to learn A* Star Path finding for which I'm using this Library - https://github.com/qiao/PathFinding.js

But I don't understand one thing how to do it.

I need to find path from player.x/player.y (player.x and player.y is both 0) to 10/10

This code return array of where I am need to move -

```
var path = finder.findPath(player.x, player.y, 10, 10, grid);
```

I am getting an array as an output which gives the positions of the player(s), but how to apply this array to my player.x and player.y?

Array structure is something like - `0: 0 1: 0 length: 2`, `0: 1 1: 0 length: 2`, ...

Thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

[Readme: Basic Usage](https://github.com/qiao/PathFinding.js/blob/master/README.md#basic-usage)

Just iterate from the first (start position) to the last (end position) entry and "move" your player accordingly

```
var path = findPath(player.x, player.y, 10, 10, grid);

for (var i = 0, length = path.length; i < length; i++) {
    player.x = path[i][0];
    player.y = path[i][1];

    // draw the new position
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for code, but in this code player don't move one by one tile but only teleporting to 10/10. Same as <code>player.x = mouse.x;</code> I am try <code>player.x += path...</code> but in this way player don't drawing.

Comment: @Veyha That's just the answer on your question _"...but how to apply this array to my player.x and player.y?"_ You should call the function for drawing the player/canvas each iteration.